How can I display icu_xx::UnicodeString types in Visual Studio Code debugger variables menu
I recently switched from working on Windows + VS to Linux + VS Code. Currently my VS Code is using LLDB debugger from the CodeLLDB extension for debugging c++.
However, i can't see values of icu_xx::UnicodeString variables while debugging. On VS it resolves them somehow and displays them to me. I've attached both screenshots, i would really appreciate it if anyone has any idea on how to get this to work. Thanks in advance!
Visual Studio Panel
Visual Studio Code Panel
So far I haven't been able to find any sources online that can help me resolve this.

From your VSC output, it looks like the type for the icu_70::UnicodeString is not available (probably it's just an opaque reference)?  Making that type available might help some, but the raw view of the type might not be that helpful.  The VS Panel just shows the string contents - which likely means there's a (probably NatVis) data formatter on the VS side.  lldb has a data formatter system like NatVis, but it doesn't ship with any formatters for these ICU types.
